# How to put cash into any UK bank account?

Tags: united-kingdom

I have exchanged some of my home currency and would like to put it in my UK bank account (Monese), however, I forgot the GBP card at home and only brought my Euro one which means that I can't use the Post Office nor PayPoint to top up my Monese accounts.

I expected to be able to just walk into any bank and be able to send the money to my bank account using the account number and sort code, however neither Halifax, HSBC nor Santander could help me as I wasn't a customer of theirs.

Isn't this possible? You can do it in any bank's branch in Sweden.

I found that I could try convincing HSBC among other banks to make me a customer but that seem like a lot of work for very little.

Comment: If you know your sort-code and account number then _in theory_ that's all you need be able to pay-in over the counter at any bank, using a paying-in slip (aka BGC or Bank Giro Credit). However, as Tom notes in his answer, many banks don't like doing this for non-customers (but might for a fee). If the Post Office has a deal with Monese, then _technically_ they could do it with just a paying-in slip, although there may be fine-print in that deal that excludes it (Monese's website doesn't mention BGC slips, but that might just be because they're "old fashoned"). It's worth asking at Post Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately then UK banks don't generally want to handle cash for someone who doesn't hold an account with them. Normally then you'd get around this by paying the cash in at a branch of your own bank, but as you're no doubt aware, Monese don't have any physical branches and only allow paying in cash using the debit card (https://monese.com/features/add-funds)

Do you know anyone you trust who has a UK bank account? If so then you could ask them to pay the cash into their account and then transfer it to you.

Alternatively, is it an option to just use the cash directly for your day to day expenses?

Comment: I don't like wearing a wallet - I usually only have my phone and keys on me.

Comment: Ended up handing the cash to a relative and I'll become a customer at a normal bank on my next visit.